# What is the unhedged version of VBU?

Tags: bonds, stock-exchanges, index-fund, vanguard, hedging

I know I should be able to find this, but I don’t see it listed anywhere online. I want to find the Canadian version of Vanguard’s total US Bond index (BND), I see VBU but this is hedged against the Canadian dollar. I see VAB but this is a Canadian Bond aggregate.

Just as VUN is the Canadian version of VTI I want the Canadian version of BND.

Comment: Are you sure it exists?

Comment: I assume there must be— why would you create a hedged version of a product (which is objectively more complex) but not an unhedged one?